# Adding values in a column in sql using variable values

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to add values in rows to my temp table using variable but it is not working. Please see the codes below. When I do this it works fine. Select command is only to see that it is working fine. The code below adds 4 rows of data in table.

```
declare @incWarehouses table (warehouse int)
insert into @incWarehouses values (400),(410),(420),(430)
select * from @incWarehouses
```

But when I try this, it does not work. I don't even know what will be the best datatype to use.

```
declare @incWarehouses table (warehouse int)
declare @reg varchar(3)  = (400),(410),(420),(430)
insert into @incWarehouses values(@reg)
```

In real, I am trying to define reg in VBA in excel and pick the values from there. I asked similar question before but probably could not explain myself properly and could not add any more comments to that too.

Any help with this will be really appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/473174/CreateplusArrayplusinplusSqlplusServer

Answer (score 0):

You can send your numbers in string e.g. '400,410,420,430' and than split it by comma.

```
insert into @incWarehouses values 
  select * from STRING_SPLIT('400,410,420,430', ',');
```

Comment: This don't seem to work Peter. Can you show how I can put this in my code to insert these values in table?